# WhatsApp URL scheme

Tags: ios, url, whatsapp.app

Can't get the Whatsapp url scheme to work. Something as simple as

```
whatsapp://send?text={{Hello World!}}
```

sends me to the last chats window  where I can select a group/contact and I get a prepopulated chat window  with the text.

But the abid parameter never does anything to avoid the contact selection.

I am using Launch Center Pro and am retrieving the abid with their [contact-abid] prompt a described here: http://help.contrast.co/hc/en-us/articles/203351237-2-3-Release-Notes

Example url:

```
whatsapp://send?text={{test}}&abid=119
```

Can anyone confirm that this actually still works? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Sandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatsaap have withdrawn it support for url scheme to send text or open particular chat in the latest version. Earlier it was possible. Only thing now you can do is open the app/ navigate to contact page.

Answer (score 0):

try using the phone number instead in international format abid=+XX123456789.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677291/6033614) in stackoverflow